# Replace body dots to spaces

Tags: jquery, replace

```
$('body, html').replace(".", " ");
```

I tried it, but this one doesn't work. I want to replace dots to spaces in the whole page.

Comment: This seems like a really bad idea.  Performance is going to be terrible unless this is a very small page.  If there are any assumptions you can make about the page, you may be able to do something more specific and not as slow.

Comment: One thing to consider. Do you want it to only replace in the text, or in the entire source. For example, it may break your page if it changes `style="width: 2.2em;"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does jQuery have a `.replace()` method? You seem to be trying to use the `String.replace()` on a jQuery object.

You could try the following instead:

```
var $body = $("body");
$body.html( $body.html().replace(/\./g, " ") );
```

Or if you wanted to do it for a more select select of elements, say only those with a certain class:

```
$(".aCertainClass").html( function(i, oldVal) {
   return oldVal.replace(/\./g, " ");
});
```

Note that `.replace()` is using a regex with the `g` flag set so it does a global replace rather than just replacing the first match.

Note also that if you replace the body's html it effectively removes and recreates all your elements so it will kill any event handlers already bound - so do it *before* attaching your handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Try [replaceAll](http://api.jquery.com/replaceAll/) functionality. You want to make sure that you replace all elements and not just one.

Update: [replaceText](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-replacetext-plugin/) can be used to replace all text present in the element.

Comment: replaceAll replaces element nodes, not text within text nodes

Answer (score 0):

If I got you, you want only change the dots into the text.

[This function at http://jsfiddle.net/KmZ5A/](http://jsfiddle.net/KmZ5A/) should do what you need:

```
  function searchDOM(element) {
      var items = [];
      items.push(element);
      var item;
      while (item = items.pop()) {
          if (typeof item != 'undefined' && item.nodeValue && item.nodeValue != null) {
              item.nodeValue = item.nodeValue.replace(/\./g,' ');
          }
          for (var key in item.childNodes) {
              var child = item.childNodes[key];
                  if (typeof child != 'undefined' && 
                      (child.nodeType == 1 || child.nodeType == 3)) {
                      items.push(child);
                 }
          }
          if (item.nodeName == "IFRAME") {
              if (!item.src) items.push(item.contentDocument.body);
          }
      }
      return null;
  }
  searchDOM(document.body);
```